# How to Identify the Client Application that Performs a Request

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, traefik, docker-network

I write a Java (Spring-Boot) service that multiple client applications can use. For maintenance/stats I would like to log which applications access the service. How can the client application be identified without trusting the client?

**Additional information**

- Multiple of those client applications are in docker containers behind a reverse proxy ([traefik](https://docs.traefik.io/)).
- Multiple of those client applications are written / maintained by the same persons. This is relevant because the request code used by a client application can be reused for another application without changing the client ID.
- I only want to hinder people copying the request code because it is faster. This solution can't be secure in my eyes and doesn't have to be. It would be good enough to recognize that two applications use the same identifier.

**Approach**

The idea could be to use public key authentication and bind the private key to something like the protocol/IP/port combination. The first part (public key auth.) would help clients that are interested in good maintenance/stats. The second part (binding) is a dead end in my eyes because I don't know what I could use for the binding:

- Protocol: Almost always the same.
- IP: Often the same because of few docker hosts.
- Port: I'm unsure right now, I guess random for the client request.
- Mac: Network segment is unpredictable.

Any ideas?

Comment: Only idea (..so far.. in a varying client structure): the clients have to tell their "identification" (however)! ..so a "clientId" must be part of "the contract" (as header/cookie/parameter...)!?

Comment: @xerx593 A client ID (a key of the public key auth.) is already provided by the approach described in the original question. This doesn't solve the problem of a copied ID.

Comment: You could enforce basic auth per client or use User-Agent in header for segregating clients. Even a unique client ID per client can be sent too, but that will add state management overhead.

Comment: @Kunal If you mean changing IDs/Tokens for the same client, that would be an interesting approach (like a CSRF token). I can look into that. I need simple request code on the client side. Therefore as you mentioned, the state management could be a problem. At least state management would be a problem after network interruption (lost token). Basic auth doesn't solve this problem better than public key auth. in my eyes. A simple unique client ID is already part of the question and the comment of xerx593.

Answer (score 1):

You can also add authorization via token in http headers. And rewrite all clients code to get tokens from environment on deploy (do not hardcode tokens in code in repository).

So even if new client appear by copy-paste of code it need to get token from you. And you can manage access of different apps and also in case of anomaly of load from one of apps you can "ban" this app (or degradate via reducing response speed for this particular token)/

Comment: Thank you. I didn't think about the token approach so far. The token could also be sendt in the body to make the request code simpler for the client. Would you please elaborate on the "getting tokens" part? I am looking for a solution that has very simple client code (modify pay load REST-call). What is a simple way for the client for the token agreement. What happens after the deployment tokens are depleted? What do you have in mind for generating / exchanging new tokens?

Comment: In case you have small amount of client ypu can generate tokens manually (and store map of tokens and users in db). Headers is better then token in body, since you can add them to get/post requests and separate logic of token check/set from process/prepare request body

Answer (score 0):

Well, I've got a doubt, but it seems to me that it is the purpose of [User-Agent request header](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent).

If queries are performed from a browser (Firefox, Chrome, etc.), you should get detailed information (providing no proxy erase it on the way).

However, for other softwares, that will likely not be as useful. For example, when using standard Java HTTP APIs, it will be set to "Java/X.x". It requires a command line argument at startup to customize it (or a call to `System.property("http-agent", ...)`, and I've got no idea how many people bother about configuring it.

For reference, I link [the following article](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-login-new-device-location). This is a tutorial for detecting client new devices from a Spring Security context, and it is based partially on *User-Agent*.

Also, [in Spring Boot reference documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.3.0.M5/reference/html/common-application-properties.html), there's mention of the following application property:

```
server.compression.excluded-user-agents= # list of user-agents to exclude from compression
```

So it looks like Spring developers consider `User-Agent` to be a viable option to determine some client specificities.

Comment: The clients can be any kind of software. Typically the clients are written in Java (Spring-Boot). I can't assume that they set the "http-agent". Your input is welcome because I didn't have the user-agent on the radar (mostly because the clients won't be browser based).